# Is it OK to encode data using key equal to data?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

For some project, I need to store some short string in encrypted form. It would be ideal for the current purposes to encrypt it using itself.

```
# This would be the usual way:
result = AES_ENCRYPT(string, key)

# but I would like to do it this way:
result = AES_ENCRYPT(string, string)
```

The same string itself would be used as the key!

The 'string' is always some short text, like 20 characters of letters and numbers. This solution seems better to me than using any hash function, since hash could lead to collisions - different strings could potentially produce the same result, which is low probability, I know, but still not zero so I want to avoid that.

My question is, is my approach safe? Encoding the data using the data itself, does it lead to any security issue? Would it mean that it could be easier to decrypt the result, if the 'attacker' knows the fact it is produced by encrypting my way? Thank you.

Note: for the simplicity of the question I didn't mention several things which are not necessary to explain. Simply trust me, I know what I am doing. I'm just asking if this approach could lead to any trouble.

Comment: How, then , would this be *decrypted* without already knowing the unencrypted text (and hence not needing to do any decryption)?

Comment: This is a homebrew hashfunction and it can lead to collisions. Use a standard hash function instead.

Comment: @Scott-Hunter I do not need to decrypt it. For the simplicity of the question I didn't mention several things which are not necessary to explain. Simply trust me, I know what I am doing. I'm just asking if this could lead to any trouble.

Comment: @TomasM Sorry, but this comment is very funny. You´re asking something to trust security-related things without knowing what it is? And who decides what facts are not important? If you really knew, you probably wouldn´t need to ask this here... (no offense)

Comment: I meant, for example, I do never need to decrypt it back, and I didn't mention this. I'm simply not asking if my approach is good idea, I am asking if it leads to collisions. Which it seems it leads, so I'll have to find better way anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption only guarantees uniqueness if the *same* key is used.  If you are using different keys then there is no guarantee of uniqueness.  If you want to guarantee uniqueness of output then keep to the same key and ensure that the input strings are unique.  Either you can accept only unique strings (like usernames) or else add salt to the strings to make otherwise identical strings unique.